# Error: impossible to replicate vector of size in mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, vegan

I have been using the following code to determine diversity (using vegan package) and it has been going well. In order to calculate diversity using vegan, you have to create a dataframe with only site by species. Then you calculate diversity and then use dplyr's mutate to be able to create a new column to your original dataframe that is your diversity metric.

```
final_corrected %>% select(eu_density, para_density, bleph_density, colp_density, rot_density, vort_density) -> final_speciesonly

H.protists <- diversity(final_speciesonly)
final_corrected %>% mutate(diversity = H.protists) -> final_diversity
```

My problem is that I tried to do this analysis again with a summarized dataset, and when I try and mutate, an error pops up:

```
summary_diversity[3:8] -> summary_speciesonly
H.protists.sum <- diversity(summary_speciesonly)
summary_speciesonly %>% mutate(diversity_sum = H.protists.sum) -> summary_diversity_total
```

Error: impossible to replicate vector of size in mutate

When I look at the differences between H.protists and H.protists.sum I find that H. protists is a named num value, whereas H.protists.sum is just a num value. Here is a header for each:

```
header(H.protists)
    1         2         3         4         5         6 
0.3144922 0.8980537 0.8740576 0.2771206 0.5701381 0.3502690 

header(H.protists.sum)
[1] 1.336860 1.331183 1.193013 1.192450 1.258912 1.412319
```

I think that this is the reason that I am getting an error message, but I am not sure how to fix it. Help?